# External network (eth0) randomly freezing, have to ifdown && ifup

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04

The external network interface (eth0) on one of our servers is periodically freezing up.  It also has a local network interface (eth1), so I'm able to connect to the server through one of the other servers in the same network.  Any connections through the external network - such as SSH from my local machine, ping from my local machine, SSH from a dev server on a different network - all time out.  While connecting through one of the other servers in its local network, I can run `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` and the interface magically works again.  If I try the `ifup` command first instead of bringing the interface down, it gives me an error message saying the interface is already up.

As a workaround, I've tried adding the following line to my root crontab:

```
55 1 * * * ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0 &> /dev/null
```

Confusingly, that doesn't actually resolve the issue.  A backup job that runs 5 minutes later is unable to copy the files to a machine outside the local network.

You can see the output of `sudo dmesg` [here](http://pastie.org/1299949).

The server is an HP ProLiant DL360 G5 running Ubuntu Lucid (10.04).  Thank you in advance for any help on how to track this issue down and resolve it!

Comment: Please can you post the output of the command `dmesg`?

Comment: Second that.. lets see some dmesg

Comment: I added a link to the [dmesg output](http://pastie.org/1299949) above.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the bottom of the output, there's definitely some relevant info.  I'm not sure how to interpret it, though.

Answer (score 2):

1- You can monitor the traffic on this interface using the command:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1518 -XX -vv -n -w /tmp/trace_file.pcap
```

Try to connect and see if the interface receives any traffic.

2- Check if you can access other machines FROM this server other than to this server using eth0.

3- Check the interface status using: `ethtool eth0`.

4- Check the interface status using the sys files under `/sys/class/net/eth0/*`

5- Check your firewall status (active or inactive) and check the rules if any.

6- Check the kernel debug messages using `dmesg` and check the system log file /var/log/messages for any errors/warnings.

Hope this will help!

Comment: This is definitely helpful - I wasn't sure how to diagnose the issue and you've given me a lot of guidance.  Thanks!  As for #2 on the list, I can (as expected) access other servers on the local network from the offending server, but nothing externally.

Comment: @Brandon: If you can post any suspicious output, I may able to help your further. Or hopefully someone else can do :)

Comment: Okay, it happened again this morning. Attempts to SSH to the server from outside the local network result in `ssh: connect to host myserver port 22: Operation timed out`.  For #1 above, I ran the command for about a minute, and it said `15 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel`. Running a second time for 2 minutes returned 0 packets for both. For #3, I got [this output](http://pastie.org/1302784).  I'm not sure which files to look for in the directory from #4. For #5, there are no rules restricting traffic.  For #6, I got [this output](http://pastie.org/1302796) about eth0.

Comment: @Brandon: I suggest that you use the default network driver (kernel module) that comes with Linux which is tg3 instead of the one you are using now!